# How to overload a destructor?

Tags: c++

How do I overload a destructor?

Comment: Since you can't, had you some idea how to use an overloaded destructor, or were you just curious?  If you want to do something other than just make two destructors for one class, bring it up and we can discuss how to accomplish it.

Comment: I wonder if it was possible, how you'd expect it to behave?

Comment: It was a question brought up by someone else. They wanted to see just how fast SO would respond.

Comment: It proved the point. They are very excited about SO now.

Comment: I went a-Googling for this exact question. If it were possible, I expected that a destructor with a given signature would be used to destruct an object that was created with a constructor of the same signature: `Node(int, Node*)` would correspond with `~Node(int, Node*)`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't.  There is only one destructor per class in C++.

What you can do is make a private destructor and then have several public methods which call the destructor in new and interesting ways.

```
class Foo {
  ~Foo() { ... }
public:
  DestroyFoo(int) { ... };
  DestroyFoo(std::string) { ... }
};
```

Comment: @Qberticus, yes it would in some ways. There's still nothing stopping the OP from creating an additional class which has simple RAII and destroys Foo in an interesting way.  Without more info from the OP I can't tell.  I'm hoping the OP considered this and is taking that into account in their solution.

Comment: I'm little confused about it. If we do so, when the object goes out of scope, whether the private destructor will also be called implicitly, or we must have to call DestroyFoo explicitly to release resources?

Answer (score 4):

Overloading means having several functions with the same name which take different arguments.  Like `swap(int &a, int &b)` and `swap(double &a, double &b)`.  A destructor takes no arguments.  Overloading it would not make sense.

If you need to do different things when destroying an object depending on certain circumstances, then you just need the appropriate if statements in your destructor to check for those circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question but the only reason why you'd want to overload a destructor would be because you want to free some resource in one destructor and leave it behind in another one, right?

Basically, you can achieve such behavior from your own destructor by using an additional boolean value which would tell you if a specific resource should be freed or not. This boolean would be set in your constructor and/or one of your other methods and in your destructor you check if it's set. If it's not set, then you'd free the resource. Otherwise, you just leave the resource and probably some other task will free it. (This would make sense when you share resources between multiple objects.)

The reason why you can't overload a destructor is because your code wouldn't have a clue about which destructor it needs to call when you destroy an object. Unless you're calling destructors badly but then you're behaving badly! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't! Each class can only have one destructor. How could you have more than one? The destructor is triggered automatically; there's no way the language would know which one to call.

Virtual destructors, however, are another matter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  You can't have 2 destructors in one class.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

You don't overload the destructor because you never call it.
That's the basic gist of it. (From what we went over in class.)